# Highcharts: Remove shadow from center of donut chart

Tags: highcharts, shadow, pie-chart, donut-chart

I have a pie chart located:

http://jsfiddle.net/PcX4b/5/

I am setting the series to look something like:

```
 series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: name,
            size: '100%',
            innerSize: '25%',
            data: innerData,
             shadow: true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: "whiteBorder",
            size: '100%',
            innerSize: '93%',
            data: outerData,
                            shadow: false,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
```

Right now the shadow for the pie chart is displaying on the outside of the pie (desired) and the donut hole (not desired). Is it possible to have it display only on the outside with out putting it on the white border series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove/set to 0 `innerSize` for a first series, see: http://jsfiddle.net/PcX4b/8/

Comment: well that is my problem I need to keep the donut hole. I just need to get rid of the shadow in the hole.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't set separately inner and outer shadows. However you can still draw a white circle in the middle to cover that shadow, see [dosc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.circle())